# How to dispatch an action within the same action itself in redux? react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Am building a countdown timer app, which switching between a work session countdown and breaktime countdown back to back until user stops it and hence the following action.

```
const setTimer = timerType => dispatch => {
let type = timerType === "Session" ? "Break":"Session";
let i = 0;
const looper = timer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        i++;
        if (store.getState().timer > 0) {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_TIMER,
                timerType: timerType,
                timer: timer -i
            }) 
            if (store.getState().timer === 0 ){
                dispatch(setTimer(type));
            } else
            looper(timer); 
        }
    }, 10)
};
switch (timerType) {
    case "Session":
        looper(store.getState().sessionLength*60);
        break;
    case "Break":
        looper(store.getState().breakLength*60);
        break;
    case "Paused":
        dispatch({
            type: SET_TIMER,
            timerType: store.getState().timerType,
            timer: store.getState().timer
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
};
```

};

The action would be called by setTimer("Session") to start counting down the session value set, and expected to follow by calling setTimer("Break") on its own back and forth when the countdown meets 0. However, it doesn't dispatch the action for the second time despite the countdown reached 0 but a console.log would be able to evoke through the if===0 statement. And actually, I couldn't manually dispatch the action again as well with a setTimeout workaround in either calling the action from react component or at the case part of the action. So I assume the problem would be the dispatch action itself. How could I make this work? Thanks for any advice.

edit;
Have already been using applyMiddleware(thunk) in the const store since it is fundamental for multiple activities within an action, or this would be an issue that I better try to write my own middleware as suggested? Because I have been using thunk for an action calling other action without issues, so I assume the problem would lay on where the action is calling itself instead of other actions? I could try to create a separate action for different timerType but would like to keep the code as short as possible ideally so I'm having this 'recursive' idea

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to make another action. My tip would be to use redux middleware like `redux-saga` or you can write your middleware that will check every dispatch of SET_TIMER. Something like this:

```js
const checkZero = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === "SET_TIMER") {
    if (store.timer <= 0) {
      //Everything there will run if timer is ===0
      //You will fire your setTimer("Break") here
      return;
   }
  }
  //If timer is however > 0 you will still dispatch the action accordingly
  return next(action);
};
```

You will also need to put this middleware to applyMiddlware while creating the store

```js
const store = createStore(
   reducer,
   applyMiddleware(
      checkZero
   )
);
```

Comment: Would this cause conflicts if I have already been using thunk at applymiddleware? Or it serves the same purpose? Because I am using thunk for middleware since it a necessity for multiple activities within actions or otherwise react would throw an exception as a reminder of async

Comment: The code just checks for the action "SET_TIMER", so that the middleware only influences the case when you try to set the timer below zero. Technically there should be only one hurtle when you try to perform side action other than dispatching action setTimer("Break") in which case you should write your side effect right down into the condition, or if it is async you should dispatch another action which will be handled by redux-thunk accordingly. Or if the middleware runs after redux-thunk everything should be fine. There shouldn't be any conflict if you keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux thunk middle wear for such a scenario.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Redux Thunk middleware enables you to create action creators that return a function rather than an action. The thunk can be used to postpone the execution of an operation or to execute it only if a specific condition is fulfilled. The storage methods dispatch and getState are sent as arguments to the inner procedure.

Comment: I am however already been using applymiddleware thunk as this would be necessary for multiple activities in an action or otherwise react would automatically throw an exception to remind you using it